# Why use jQuery().each() in a plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've seen a couple of tutorials that show a similar approach to making jquery plugins, and which both use the $("someSelector").each() function to act on a collection. The basic model is like this:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    return this.each( function( index, element ) {
      // do something, e.g.:
      $(element).css("color", "red");
    }
  }
})( jQuery );
```

This works, but it also works when not using each() as in:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    return this.css("color", "red");
    }
  }
})( jQuery );
```

I understand that each() could be necessary if I wanted to act differently on different items in my collection — say, if I wanted to change odd elements blue and even elements red. But if I'm doing the same thing for all, is there any reason to use each?

Comment: in case you use a class selector - then it will loop through each instance of the object when you instantiate the function and apply it only to that instance.  For example you may need to do calculations based on that elements position

Comment: I see. In other words, my second version, which simply returns this.css("color", "red") would be fine for something very simply. If I wanted to set the color based on a data attribute, for example, I'd need to use each().

Comment: for the `this.css` jQuery would internally loop all elements already because that's how jQuery works. For other methods you create though it is a different story ...  rule of thumb ...always use `each` in plugin